# Vim snipmate plugin not working

Tags: ubuntu, vim

my snipmate installed in pathogen is not working in my vim. I dont know what's wrong or what should I do??

this is my .vim

```
├── autoload
│   └── pathogen.vim
├── bundle
│   ├── nerdtree
│   │   ├── autoload
│   │   │   ├── nerdtree
│   │   │   │   └── ui_glue.vim
│   │   │   └── nerdtree.vim
│   │   ├── doc
│   │   │   ├── NERD_tree.txt
│   │   │   └── tags
│   │   ├── lib
│   │   │   └── nerdtree
│   │   │       ├── bookmark.vim
│   │   │       ├── creator.vim
│   │   │       ├── event.vim
│   │   │       ├── flag_set.vim
│   │   │       ├── key_map.vim
│   │   │       ├── menu_controller.vim
│   │   │       ├── menu_item.vim
│   │   │       ├── nerdtree.vim
│   │   │       ├── notifier.vim
│   │   │       ├── opener.vim
│   │   │       ├── path.vim
│   │   │       ├── tree_dir_node.vim
│   │   │       ├── tree_file_node.vim
│   │   │       └── ui.vim
│   │   ├── nerdtree_plugin
│   │   │   ├── exec_menuitem.vim
│   │   │   └── fs_menu.vim
│   │   ├── plugin
│   │   │   └── NERD_tree.vim
│   │   ├── README.markdown
│   │   └── syntax
│   │       └── nerdtree.vim
│   ├── tlib_vim
│   │   ├── addon-info.json
│   │   ├── autoload
│   │   │   ├── tinykeymap
│   │   │   │   └── map
│   │   │   │       └── para_move.vim
│   │   │   ├── tlib
│   │   │   │   ├── agent.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── arg.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── autocmdgroup.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── balloon.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── bitwise.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── buffer.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── cache.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── char.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── cmd.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── comments.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── date.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── dir.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── eval.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── file.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── Filter_cnfd.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── Filter_cnf.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── Filter_fuzzy.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── Filter_glob.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── fixes.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── grep.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── hash.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── hook.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── input.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── list.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── map.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── normal.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── notify.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── number.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── Object.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── paragraph.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── persistent.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── progressbar.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── rx.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── scratch.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── signs.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── string.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── syntax.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── sys.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── tab.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── tag.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── TestChild.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── Test.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── textobjects.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── time.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── type.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── url.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── var.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── vcs.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── vim.vim
│   │   │   │   ├── win.vim
│   │   │   │   └── World.vim
│   │   │   └── tlib.vim
│   │   ├── CHANGES.TXT
│   │   ├── doc
│   │   │   ├── tags
│   │   │   └── tlib.txt
│   │   ├── etc
│   │   │   └── tpl_tlib.txt
│   │   ├── plugin
│   │   │   └── 02tlib.vim
│   │   ├── README
│   │   ├── samples
│   │   │   └── tlib
│   │   │       └── input
│   │   │           └── tlib_input_list.vim
│   │   ├── scripts
│   │   │   └── create_crc_table.rb
│   │   ├── spec
│   │   │   └── tlib
│   │   │       ├── arg.vim
│   │   │       ├── date.vim
│   │   │       ├── file.vim
│   │   │       ├── hash.vim
│   │   │       ├── input.vim
│   │   │       ├── list.vim
│   │   │       ├── rx.vim
│   │   │       ├── string.vim
│   │   │       ├── url.vim
│   │   │       └── var.vim
│   │   └── test
│   │       └── tlib.vim
│   ├── vim-addon-mw-utils
│   │   ├── autoload
│   │   │   ├── buf_utils.vim
│   │   │   ├── cached_file_contents.vim
│   │   │   ├── env_reload.vim
│   │   │   ├── funcref.vim
│   │   │   ├── glob.vim
│   │   │   ├── tiny_cmd.vim
│   │   │   └── tovl
│   │   │       ├── scratch_buffer.vim
│   │   │       └── ui
│   │   │           └── filter_list.vim
│   │   ├── doc
│   │   │   ├── cached_file_contents.txt
│   │   │   ├── funcref.txt
│   │   │   ├── tags
│   │   │   └── tiny_cmd.txt
│   │   └── vim-addon-mw-utils-addon-info.txt
│   ├── vim-sensible
│   │   ├── plugin
│   │   │   └── sensible.vim
│   │   └── README.markdown
│   └── vim-snipmate
│       ├── addon-info.json
│       ├── after
│       │   └── plugin
│       │       └── snipMate.vim
│       ├── autoload
│       │   ├── snipmate
│       │   │   ├── jumping.vim
│       │   │   ├── legacy.vim
│       │   │   ├── parse.vim
│       │   │   └── util.vim
│       │   ├── snipMate_python_demo.vim
│       │   └── snipMate.vim
│       ├── Contributors.md
│       ├── doc
│       │   ├── SnipMate.txt
│       │   └── tags
│       ├── ftplugin
│       │   ├── html_snip_helper.vim
│       │   └── snippets.vim
│       ├── indent
│       │   └── snippets.vim
│       ├── plugin
│       │   └── snipMate.vim
│       ├── README.md
│       ├── syntax
│       │   ├── snippets.vim
│       │   └── snippet.vim
│       └── t
│           ├── jumping.vim
│           ├── parser.vim
│           └── tests.sh
├── nerdtree
│   ├── autoload
│   │   ├── nerdtree
│   │   │   └── ui_glue.vim
│   │   └── nerdtree.vim
│   ├── doc
│   │   ├── NERD_tree.txt
│   │   └── tags
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── nerdtree
│   │       ├── bookmark.vim
│   │       ├── creator.vim
│   │       ├── event.vim
│   │       ├── flag_set.vim
│   │       ├── key_map.vim
│   │       ├── menu_controller.vim
│   │       ├── menu_item.vim
│   │       ├── nerdtree.vim
│   │       ├── notifier.vim
│   │       ├── opener.vim
│   │       ├── path.vim
│   │       ├── tree_dir_node.vim
│   │       ├── tree_file_node.vim
│   │       └── ui.vim
│   ├── nerdtree_plugin
│   │   ├── exec_menuitem.vim
│   │   └── fs_menu.vim
│   ├── plugin
│   │   └── NERD_tree.vim
│   ├── README.markdown
│   └── syntax
│       └── nerdtree.vim
├── tlib_vim
│   ├── addon-info.json
│   ├── autoload
│   │   ├── tinykeymap
│   │   │   └── map
│   │   │       └── para_move.vim
│   │   ├── tlib
│   │   │   ├── agent.vim
│   │   │   ├── arg.vim
│   │   │   ├── autocmdgroup.vim
│   │   │   ├── balloon.vim
│   │   │   ├── bitwise.vim
│   │   │   ├── buffer.vim
│   │   │   ├── cache.vim
│   │   │   ├── char.vim
│   │   │   ├── cmd.vim
│   │   │   ├── comments.vim
│   │   │   ├── date.vim
│   │   │   ├── dir.vim
│   │   │   ├── eval.vim
│   │   │   ├── file.vim
│   │   │   ├── Filter_cnfd.vim
│   │   │   ├── Filter_cnf.vim
│   │   │   ├── Filter_fuzzy.vim
│   │   │   ├── Filter_glob.vim
│   │   │   ├── fixes.vim
│   │   │   ├── grep.vim
│   │   │   ├── hash.vim
│   │   │   ├── hook.vim
│   │   │   ├── input.vim
│   │   │   ├── list.vim
│   │   │   ├── map.vim
│   │   │   ├── normal.vim
│   │   │   ├── notify.vim
│   │   │   ├── number.vim
│   │   │   ├── Object.vim
│   │   │   ├── paragraph.vim
│   │   │   ├── persistent.vim
│   │   │   ├── progressbar.vim
│   │   │   ├── rx.vim
│   │   │   ├── scratch.vim
│   │   │   ├── signs.vim
│   │   │   ├── string.vim
│   │   │   ├── syntax.vim
│   │   │   ├── sys.vim
│   │   │   ├── tab.vim
│   │   │   ├── tag.vim
│   │   │   ├── TestChild.vim
│   │   │   ├── Test.vim
│   │   │   ├── textobjects.vim
│   │   │   ├── time.vim
│   │   │   ├── type.vim
│   │   │   ├── url.vim
│   │   │   ├── var.vim
│   │   │   ├── vcs.vim
│   │   │   ├── vim.vim
│   │   │   ├── win.vim
│   │   │   └── World.vim
│   │   └── tlib.vim
│   ├── CHANGES.TXT
│   ├── doc
│   │   ├── tags
│   │   └── tlib.txt
│   ├── etc
│   │   └── tpl_tlib.txt
│   ├── plugin
│   │   └── 02tlib.vim
│   ├── README
│   ├── samples
│   │   └── tlib
│   │       └── input
│   │           └── tlib_input_list.vim
│   ├── scripts
│   │   └── create_crc_table.rb
│   ├── spec
│   │   └── tlib
│   │       ├── arg.vim
│   │       ├── date.vim
│   │       ├── file.vim
│   │       ├── hash.vim
│   │       ├── input.vim
│   │       ├── list.vim
│   │       ├── rx.vim
│   │       ├── string.vim
│   │       ├── url.vim
│   │       └── var.vim
│   └── test
│       └── tlib.vim
├── vim-addon-mw-utils
│   ├── autoload
│   │   ├── buf_utils.vim
│   │   ├── cached_file_contents.vim
│   │   ├── env_reload.vim
│   │   ├── funcref.vim
│   │   ├── glob.vim
│   │   ├── tiny_cmd.vim
│   │   └── tovl
│   │       ├── scratch_buffer.vim
│   │       └── ui
│   │           └── filter_list.vim
│   ├── doc
│   │   ├── cached_file_contents.txt
│   │   ├── funcref.txt
│   │   ├── tags
│   │   └── tiny_cmd.txt
│   └── vim-addon-mw-utils-addon-info.txt
├── vim-sensible
│   ├── plugin
│   │   └── sensible.vim
│   └── README.markdown
└── vim-snipmate
    ├── addon-info.json
    ├── after
    │   └── plugin
    │       └── snipMate.vim
    ├── autoload
    │   ├── snipmate
    │   │   ├── jumping.vim
    │   │   ├── legacy.vim
    │   │   ├── parse.vim
    │   │   └── util.vim
    │   ├── snipMate_python_demo.vim
    │   └── snipMate.vim
    ├── Contributors.md
    ├── doc
    │   ├── SnipMate.txt
    │   └── tags
    ├── ftplugin
    │   ├── html_snip_helper.vim
    │   └── snippets.vim
    ├── indent
    │   └── snippets.vim
    ├── plugin
    │   └── snipMate.vim
    ├── README.md
    ├── syntax
    │   ├── snippets.vim
    │   └── snippet.vim
    └── t
        ├── jumping.vim
        ├── parser.vim
        └── tests.sh
```

I followed the installation process in github.

and this is what I have in my .vimrc

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

set ts=4
set ai
set shiftwidth=4
syn on
set mouse=a
au BufRead,BufNewFile jquery.*.js set ft=javascript syntax=jquery
color evening
filetype on
set tabpagemax=25
set smartindent
set showmatch
set vb t_vb=
set ruler
set incsearch
set nocompatible
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.php set ft=php.html
filetype plugin on
filetype indent plugin on | syn on
filetype plugin on

autocmd vimenter * NERDTree
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists("s:std_in") | NERDTree | endif
```

help anyone :) thanks..!

Comment: If you have Python installed and vim compiled with Python support, you might give [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) a try. It is a lot more powerful. You can use run vimscript and python code in the expansion of snippets. Both ultisnips and snipmate have repositiries of snippets separated from the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

1. All your plugins are duplicated. Since you use Pathogen, you only need those in `bundle` so you should remove `nerdtree/`, `tlib_vim/`, `vim-addon-mw-utils`, `vim-sensible` and `vim-snipmate` from `~/.vim/`.
2. Snipmate needs snippets to "work" but you didn't install any.